# What happened to the GitHub Wikis when I turned my repo to Private?

Tags: github

I used to have a public GitHub repo with a wiki section filled with my project content.

Then I turned the repo from public to private.

Since there I do not have a Premium GitHub account, I cannot have a GitHub repo with a private wiki.

But what happened to the wiki I had when the repo was public?

I've read through docs at:

- https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/changing-access-permissions-for-wikis
- https://docs.github.com/en/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/about-wikis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not have a Premium GitHub account, you would not have the option to make a private repository with a wiki. In this case, it is likely that the wiki associated with the repository is not accessible when you changed the repository from public to private, what happens if you change the samething back to public, do you see the wiki again? if so then its by design, as soon as you turn private you dont have access unless you upgrade to premium I think

Wiki is hidden is when it goes private. Wiki is restored when you switch back to public.

Comment: I didn't want to switch my repo back to public but I just now thought of doing this with a new test repo.  The result is that the wiki is preserved and then restored when switched back to public.

Comment: Right ok thanks for confirming, I'll update the answer to reflect this